# Can't import the named export 'MapperKind' from non EcmaScript module

Tags: mapper, gql

I made a query and useUser function as below:

```
const ME_QUERY = gql`
  query me {
    me {
      username
      avatar
    }
  }
`;

function useUser() {
  const isLoggedIn = useReactiveVar(isLoggedInVar);
  const { data, error } = useQuery(ME_QUERY, {
    skip: !isLoggedIn,
  });
  console.log(data, error);
  return;
}
export default useUser;
```

And I put it in other js file:

```
const loggedInUser = useUser();
```

But it shows me below error message in Terminal.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@graphql-tools/mock/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'MapperKind' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

what does 'MapperKind' means?
And what it shows me the error? please help me.